# Non-RAC single instance with ASM startup query

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, startup, oracle-asm

How to start a non-rac single instance with ASM file system. As in the case of RAC after reboot of server, the ASM and CRS resources startup automatically.. but with non-RAC but with ASM storage, what is the right way to start the database?

Is there anything specific that should be given attention to start the database?

Start the ASM instance and mount all the diskgroups and then start the database?

Correct me/add if i'm wrong.

Server- RHEL Database - 12c

Comment: If you have install Oracle Database 12c on top of Grid Infrastructure then your database must be registered to Oracle Restart(Which will automatically starts your database). In order to use ASM you must install Grid Infrastructure.

Comment: ASM is in use. But it won't come up automatically. Should I enable something specifically for it?

Comment: use 'srvctl config database -d your db name' to check management policy. If it is 'automatic' the database should run upon server startup. if it is manual then it wont come itself.

Comment: Use 'srvctl modify database -d db_unique_name -policy AUTOMATIC|MANUAL' to change management policy.

Comment: ok will check that and comeback. Should I also check if ASM instance, listener is also added for restart?

Answer (score 1):

Check if autostart for Oracle Restart is enabled:

```
$ cat /etc/oracle/scls_scr/$HOSTNAME/oracle/ohasdstr
enable
```

If it is not enabled, then enable it:

```
crsctl enable has
```

Check if ASM autostart is enabled:

```
crsctl stat res ora.asm
```

If ASM is not registered in GI, add it with:

```
srvctl add asm ...
```

Check if used diskgroups are registered:

```
srvctl status diskgroup -g DATA
crsctl stat res ora.DATA.dg
```

If they are not registered, add them with:

```
srvctl add diskgroup ...
```

Check if the database is registered and autostart is enabled:

```
srvctl config database -d ORCL
```

If it is not, register and enable:

```
srvctl add database ...
srvctl enable database ...
```

Finally make sure you define the used ASM diskgroups as dependencies:

```
srvctl modify database -d ORCL -diskgroup "DATA,FRA"
```

You can also check the listener:

```
srvctl config listener
```

If it does not exist, you can add with:

```
srvctl add listener ...
```

You do not need to start or stop anything manually with sqlplus, lsnrctl. Oracle Restart takes care of that based on the defined start/stop options and dependencies.

Comment: when I run crsctl stat res ora.asm -- it gives target is online. does that mean it is registered for restart?

Comment: And all the diskgroups are showing 'running' in the srvctl command.